# Настройка GitHub Actions для отображения покрытия тестами в readme

Tags: python, github, github-actions

Проблема такая. Я создал файл для GitHub Actions, который с помощью линтера проверяет мой Python код. Теперь мне надо добавить в этот же файл код, который будет проверять с помощью coverage покрытие моего кода тестами. Только вот я не знаю, как это сделать. И ещё нужно, чтобы в readme файле появились проценты покрытия.

Мой yml файл:

```yaml
name: Python-package

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.9]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
```

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего, нужно запустить сами тесты, и сделать вывод coverage этих тестов. Я обычно использую `pytest` с плагином `pytest-cov`.

Добавляем шаг:

```yaml
    - name: Run tests with pytest
      run: |
        # Вместо запуска pip на этом шаге можно добавить установку pytest-cov на одном из предыдущих шагов
        pip install pytest-cov
        pytest --cov=./ --cov-report=xml
```

Дальше, для отображения покрытия в readme нужно из данных о покрытии создать бейдж, и этот бейдж вставить в readme. Можно использовать такие сервисы как https://codecov.io, https://coveralls.io, https://codeclimate.com. Регистрируемся на выбранном сервисе, настраиваем интеграцию, добавляем шаг для отправки данных на сервис.

Ниже пример для codecov.io (более полный пример см. [здесь](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-action#usage)):

```yaml
    - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2
      with:
        files: coverage.xml
        flags: unittests
        env_vars: OS,PYTHON
        fail_ci_if_error: true
```

Пример для coveralls.io:

```yaml
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest --cov=./
    - name: Upload coverage data to coveralls.io
      run: |
        pip install coveralls
        coveralls --service=github
```

Также есть возможность создавать бейдж без использования сторонних сервисов, для этого через github actions генерируется  gist с данными покрытия, потом с помощью [dynamic-badges-action](https://github.com/Schneegans/dynamic-badges-action) генерируется сам бейдж. Пример есть здесь, правда он написан для node.js проекта:

[Coverage Badge with GitHub Actions - FINALLY!](https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/coverage-badge-with-github-actions-finally-59fa)